# How can I prevent my program from freezing in tkinter when using the after() function?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttkbootstrap

```
import ttkbootstrap as tb


def timer():
    global hours, minutes, seconds
    hours = 0
    minutes = 0
    seconds = 0

    if hours_combo.get() != "":
        hours = hours_combo.get()
        hours = int(hours)
        
    if minutes_combo.get() != "":
        minutes = minutes_combo.get()
        minutes = int(minutes)
        
    if seconds_combo.get() != "":
        seconds = seconds_combo.get()
        seconds = int(seconds)
    
    root.after(((1000 * ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds))), finish)
    countdown()

def countdown():
    for count in range(seconds, 0, -1):
        countdown_seconds = count % 60
        countdown_minutes = int(count / 60) % 60
        countdown_hours = int(count / 3600)
        print(f"{countdown_hours:02}:{countdown_minutes:02}:{countdown_seconds:02}")
        root.after(1000)

def finish():
    print("Done")
```

When I called the countdown function, the program executes correctly and the countdown prints but the Gui freezes. I thought previously that the after() function prevented this from happening. I removed the variable declarations as they aren't relevant. I attempted to use multiprocessing or threading but neither solution worked.

Comment: Note that `.after(1000)` is the same as `sleep(1)`.

Comment: Where are the `root`, `seconds_combo`, `minutes_combo`, `seconds_combo`, `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds` definitions?

Comment: You would use ```.after()``` for recursing a function. Eg: ```root.after(1000, countdown)```

Comment: You need a tab after the `for count in range(seconds, 0, -1):` loop.

Comment: FWIW: you can also just use `if <whatever>_combo.get()` instead of `if <whatever>_combo.get() != ""` since non-empty strings are "truthy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you use `after` to perform this task.  You have `after` call that same function one second later, until the counter goes to zero.  Remember that your event callbacks must run VERY quickly.  You can't ever delay in an event callback.

```
seconds = 0
def timer():
    global seconds
    hours = 0
    minutes = 0
    seconds = 0

    if hours_combo.get() != "":
        hours = hours_combo.get()
        hours = int(hours)
        
    if minutes_combo.get() != "":
        minutes = minutes_combo.get()
        minutes = int(minutes)
        
    if seconds_combo.get() != "":
        seconds = seconds_combo.get()
        seconds = int(seconds)

    seconds = hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds
    
    countdown()

def countdown():
    global seconds
    seconds -= 1
    countdown_seconds = seconds % 60
    countdown_minutes = seconds // 60 % 60
    countdown_hours = seconds // 3600
    print(f"{countdown_hours:02}:{countdown_minutes:02}:{countdown_seconds:02}")

    if seconds:
        root.after(1000, countdown)
    else:
        print("Done")
```